# Comparing objects that implement the same interface with javers

Tags: java, object, compare, javers

I'm using javers (https://javers.org/) and trying to compare two objects that implement the same interface. As an example I set up a test with apples and oranges. Apples to Apples works fine, but not Apples to Oranges. It seems to  run the compare but doesn't pick up the new values.

This works fine if I have a Fruit super class and apples and oranges that extend it but no luck with interfaces.
Anybody out there familiar with this API that could point me in the right direction would be great.

Here's the model code:

```
@TypeName("FruitIface")
@Entity
public interface FruitIface {

public final static String SIZE_SMALL = "Small";
public final static String SIZE_LARGE = "Large";
public final static String CONDITION_RIPE = "Ripe";
public final static String CONDITION_NOT_RIPE = "Not Ripe";

public String getSize();
public String getCondition();
public Double getWeight();
public Date getSellBy();

}



@TypeName("FruitIface")
@Entity
public class Apple implements FruitIface {


private String size;
private String condition;
private Double weight;
private Date sellBy;
@Id
private String compareId;

public Apple (String id,String size, String condition, Double weight, Date sellBy){
    this.compareId = id;
    this.size = size;
    this.condition = condition;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.sellBy = sellBy;
}
    ....

}


@TypeName("FruitIface")
@Entity
public class Orange implements FruitIface {

@PropertyName("size")
private String size;
private String condition;
private Double weight;
private Date sellBy;
@Id
private String compareId;


public Orange (String id, String size, String condition, Double weight, Date sellBy){
    this.compareId = id;
    this.size = size;
    this.condition = condition;
    this.weight = weight;
    this.sellBy = sellBy;
}
....
}
```

Test cases:

```
@Test public void testCompareAppleToAppleIface() {
    Apple appleOne = new Apple("01",FruitIface.SIZE_LARGE,FruitIface.CONDITION_RIPE, 0.3, new Date());
    Apple appleTwo = new Apple("01",FruitIface.SIZE_SMALL,FruitIface.CONDITION_RIPE, 0.2, new Date());

    LOGGER.info("\n\nComparing apples to apples...");
    Diff diff = javers.compare(appleOne, appleTwo);
    LOGGER.info("diff: " + diff);

}


@Test public void testCompareAppleAndOrangeIface() {
    Apple apple = new Apple("01",FruitIface.SIZE_LARGE,FruitIface.CONDITION_RIPE, 0.3, new Date()); //(String size, String condition, Double weight, Date sellBy)
    Orange orange = new Orange("01",FruitIface.SIZE_SMALL,FruitIface.CONDITION_RIPE, 0.2, new Date());


    LOGGER.info("\n\nComparing apples and oranges IFace...");
    Diff diff = javers.compare(apple, orange);
    LOGGER.info("diff: " + diff);
}
```

Results:

```
Comparing apples to apples...
[main] INFO xxx.compare.test.JaversCompareTestIface - diff: Diff:
1. ValueChange{globalId:'FruitIface/01', property:'size', oldVal:'Large', newVal:'Small'}
2. ValueChange{globalId:'FruitIface/01', property:'weight', oldVal:'0.3', newVal:'0.2'}


Comparing apples and oranges IFace...
[main] INFO xxx.compare.test.JaversCompareTestIface - diff: Diff:
1. ValueChange{globalId:'FruitIface/01', property:'size', oldVal:'Large', newVal:''}
2. ValueChange{globalId:'FruitIface/01', property:'condition', oldVal:'Ripe', newVal:''}
3. ValueChange{globalId:'FruitIface/01', property:'weight', oldVal:'0.3', newVal:''}
4. ValueChange{globalId:'FruitIface/01', property:'sellBy', oldVal:'Thu Aug 10 12:14:45 PDT 2017', newVal:''}
5. ValueChange{globalId:'FruitIface/01', property:'compareId', oldVal:'01', newVal:''}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same @TypeName for multiple classes is a misuse for the same reasons like using the same class name for multiple Java classes.

JaVers should throw an exception in this case, instead you are getting somehow random results because JaVers type system gets confused.

In the current version of JaVers, you can't compare Apples with Oranges even if both of them implement Fruit interface. 
JaVers matches objects with the same `GlobalId` and compares them.
When you have Apple with id 1 and Orange with id 1, their GlobalIds are `Apple#1` and `Orange#1` so they won't be matches as two versions of the same object.

Comment: I understand your response...sort of. What I'm trying to do is to compare apples and oranges as fruit. So I have a fruit interface and two implementations of the interface (apple and orange). I tried removing all annotations from the apple and orange and then running the test. What i get back from javers is new object & object removed. According to the docs it sounds possible to compare objects with the same iface:
Mapping ProTips
    First, try to map high level abstract classes or interfaces. For example, if all of your Entities extend some abstract class, you should map only this class.

Comment: **Hmmm. The strategy works if I extend classes...**
@TypeName("FruitSuper")
@Entity
public class FruitSuper {...}
@TypeName("FruitSuper")
public class AppleSub extends FruitSuper {...}
@TypeName("FruitSuper")
public class OrangeSub extends FruitSuper {...}
Comparing apples and oranges Subclass same id...
[main] INFO xxx.compare.test.JaversCompareTestSuper - diff: Diff:
1. ValueChange{globalId:'FruitSuper/01', property:'size', oldVal:'Large', newVal:'Small'}
2. ValueChange{globalId:'FruitSuper/01', property:'weight', oldVal:'0.3', newVal:'0.2'}
**Is it a feature or a bug?**

Comment: That's how inheritance and interfaces work in Java. If Apple extends Fruit and Orange extends Fruit, both are Fruits so can be compared. If Apple implements Serializable and Orange implements Serializable it doesn't mean that Apple can be compared to Orange.

Comment: Yes, this circles back to my original question. Javers allows me to compare two subclasses of Fruit (apple and orange) as Fruit. 
It doesn't allow me to compare two objects (apple and orange) that implement a Fruit interface, even though the globalId matches.
Is that by design? 
I got the impression from the docs that you could compare two objects that share an interface, i.e. FruitIface

Comment: Yes, it's by design and won't be changed. Btw. could you point the section in docs which could be misleading?

Comment: Too bad, I think it would be a great feature, and based on the test output it seems like it _almost_ works. The docs are in this [page](https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/) Under Mapping Configuration > Mapping ProTips. It says _First, try to map high level abstract classes or interfaces._ I think the word "interfaces" should be struck. There's no point in mapping the interfaces if I can't compare by interface.I may as well map the implementations. Or maybe I don't fully understand how a mapped interface would be used. Thanks for your help on this!